# Accessing class members causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt

My class "ComponentArea" looks like this:

```
#ifndef COMPONENTAREA_H
#define COMPONENTAREA_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QtDesigner/QtDesigner>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QPainter>

#include <Components/Sockets/socket.h>

class ComponentArea : public QScrollArea
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    ComponentArea(QWidget* parent = 0);
    void connectSockets(Socket* a, Socket* b);
    void childBlock_childSocket_mousePressEvent(Socket* sender, QMouseEvent* event);
    void childBlock_childSocket_mouseReleaseEvent(Socket* sender, QMouseEvent* event);

private:

    Socket* pressedSocket;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};

#endif // COMPONENTAREA_H
```

In the constructor, I set pressedSocket to 0:

```
pressedSocket = 0;
```

Whenever I try to use pressedSocket, in one of the events, I get a Segmentation Fault:

```
void ComponentArea::childBlock_childSocket_mousePressEvent(Socket *sender, QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if((pressedSocket == 0) && (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)) //SIGSEGV here
    {
        pressedSocket = sender;
    }
}
```

I get this effect with every member, even with simple booleans.
I don't see what I am doing wrong. Any advices? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `ComponentArea` object is invalid.

Comment: When do you get a segfault? At the point of assignment, or later, when you try to use that value?

Comment: From where is this function being called?

Answer (score 0):

Probably either `this` or `event` is null. Check whether you instantiated your class.

If you developing on linux then you can run your program with [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html). It will exactly say what went wrong, just carefully read its messages.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a "use after free" problem, which means you're trying to access an object that has already been deleted. Did you check it?

E.g. put a breakpoint to the line where your SIGSEGV happens. Inspect the *this* pointer and value of your *pressedSocket* member. If you're lucky it'll have an obscure value like "0xfeeefeee" - in that case your object is not existing anymore, so you cannot access anything there.

Otherwise it might be that you're trying to dereference a NULL pointer, in this case the *this* shows up as something like "0x00000000". (As János Roden just pointed out.)